# angular - using async pipe on observable<Object> and bind it to local variable in html

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, local-variables, angular2-observables

Hi I have a observable user$ with a lot of properties (name, title, address...)

```
component{
  user$:Observerable<User>;
  constructor(private userService:UserService){
    this.user$ = this.userService.someMethodReturningObservable$()
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use the async pipe in the html template to subscribe to it and bind it to a local variable like this

```
<div #user="user$ | async">
  <h3> {{user.name}}
</div>
```

I know can can subscribe to it in the constructor and then unsubscribe in OnLeave/OnDestroy but I was just curious if I could use the async pipe.

Cheers

Comment: As I know async pipe only works with *ngFor ? in that you can do this `*ngFor="let u of (user = (user$ | async))"` but seems fishy. need a bit practical.

Comment: not async can work on a single observable as well, see ngrx/store :)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`#` is [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars). It defers to DOM element and cannot be used like that.

Local variables aren't implemented in Angular as of now, [this closed issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451) can be monitored for the references to related issues.

Since Angular 4 the syntax of `ngIf` and `ngFor` directives was updated to allow local variables. See [`ngIf` reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) for details. So it is possible to do

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async; let user">
  <h3> {{user.name}} </h3>
</div>
```

This will create `div` wrapper element and will provide cloaking behaviour to it, so there's no need for `?.` 'Elvis' operator.

If no extra markup is desirable, it can be changed to

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async; let user">...</ng-container>
```

If cloaking behaviour is not desirable, the expression can be changed to truthy placeholder value.

A placeholder can be empty object for object value,

```
<div *ngIf="(user$ | async) || {}; let user">
  <h3> {{user?.name}} </h3>
</div>
```

Or a space for primitive value,

```
<div *ngIf="(primitive$ | async) || ' '; let primitive">
  <h3> {{primitive}} </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working for me, however I'm getting a warning saying `'of' expected`.  I think this is a tslint warning, but having a hard time finding any info for it.

Comment: @Blexy It's hard to say what's wrong here, it looks like a part of some message.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the same error with the `'of' expected`, I was trying to reform it so it would make sense to both the linter and Angular, but that turns out to be a bit harder then expected. Feels like some automagic with the `async` pipe.

Comment: @BjornSchijff did you identify a workaround for `'of' expected`?

Comment: @Blexy You didn't mention that this is [IDE warning](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000491110-Angular-4-HTML-template-of-expected-error), in fact. TSLint doesn't care about templates.

Comment: @Blexy see the answer of Wooli Design, this is what worked for me.
In regards to your IDE warning; if you use `ng cli`, this does care about templates and will throw errors if incompatibilities have been found.

Comment: @BjornSchijff To my knowledge, `as` and `let` are interchangeable, the latter is closer to how the directive is desugared without `*`, both are supported by Angular and Angular CLI. Do you have information that contradicts this?

Answer (score 43):

@Bjorn Schijff and @estus

Instead of:

```
<div *ngIf="(user$ | async) || {}; let user">
```

Do:

```
<div *ngIf="(user | async) as user">
```

Comment: Yes, I have angular 4.4.3

Comment: Both `as` and `let` are supported by the framework. Why exactly should it be done this way and not another?

Comment: I have no idea, it worked with angular 4.4.3. Maybe both works with angular 5.

Comment: Example given by @WooliDesign works, here is the doc [link for ref](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: You'll get unresolved variable error in Angular 8 by doing so.

Comment: If the user is not logged in, #2 will not get evaluated... big difference

Answer (score 8):

Use following syntax:

```
<div *ngIf="(user | async) as user">
```

**Note:** The addition of “*as user*” at the end of the expression.

What this will do is wait until user$ | async has evaluated, and bind the result to the value of user (non-dollar-suffixed).

Comment: How is this any different from @WooliDesign's answer?

Answer (score 1):

For `*ngFor` it's possible with added `*ngIf` directive on parent element:

```js
    <ul *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
      <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.name}}</li>
      <li *ngIf="!users.length">No users</li>
    </ul>
```

If there's already a structural directive on the parent element, then introduction of an intermediate element like `<ng-container>` may be necessary.