# Angular 2 - Manipulating rxjs Observable in a view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting started with Observable in Angular 2 and I can't figure out how to use them properly in my views.

I'm using Angular 2 with angular-redux, and using the `@select()` decorator to retrieve my `selectedMovie$` from the redux store. This part works fine, the component basically dispatch a redux event to set the default `selectedMovie$` upon init. The redux store is correctly updated, but when I try to consumme it in the view, I face some issues.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, select } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { MovieActions} from '../store/app.actions';
import { IAppState} from '../store/reducers';
import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IMovie } from '../movie.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies-container',
  templateUrl: './movies-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies-container.component.css'],
  providers: [MovieService]
})
export class MoviesContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: Array<IMovie>;
  @select() readonly selectedMovie$: Observable<IMovie>; // HERE - Get data from the redux store

  constructor(
    private movieService: MovieService,
    private movieActions: MovieActions,
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Fetch movies and use the first one as default displayed movie.
    this.getMovies() // HERE - Takes the first movie and make it the default selectedMovie by dispatching a redux action
      .then(movies =>
        this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.movieActions.changeSelectedMovie(this.movies[0]))
      );
  }

  getMovies() { // HERE: Call an API, returns an array of movies in data.results
    return this.movieService.getMostPopular()
      .then(data => this.movies = data.results);
  }

  onSelect(movie: IMovie) {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.movieActions.changeSelectedMovie(movie));
  }
}
```

Here comes the view:

```
<div *ngIf="movies">
  <md-list>
    <h3 md-subheader>Most popular movies NOW!</h3>
    <pre>
      {{(selectedMovie$ | async | json).id}} // This fails and displays nothing. I'd expect it to display the movie id
    </pre>
    <md-list-item
      *ngFor="let movie of movies"
      [class.selected]="movie.id === (selectedMovie$ | async | json).id" // This is a real deal, I don't know what's the syntax to use. I wanted to compare ids
      (click)="onSelect(movie)"
    >
      <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92{{movie.poster_path}}" />
      {{movie.title}}
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>

  <app-movie-card [movie]="selectedMovie$ | async | json"></app-movie-card> // This component gets the object correctly formatted
</div>
```

Maybe I'm just not using the right syntax. Or maybe I shouldn't use an Observer in the view in the first place?

---

Edit: Solution

```
<div *ngIf="movies && (selectedMovie$ | async); let selectedMovie">
  <md-list>
    <h3 md-subheader>Most popular movies NOW!</h3>
    <md-list-item
      *ngFor="let movie of movies"
      [class.selected]="movie.id === selectedMovie.id"
      (click)="onSelect(movie)"
    >
      <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92{{movie.poster_path}}" />
      {{movie.title}}
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>

  <app-movie-card [movie]="selectedMovie"></app-movie-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem results from a common misconception that JSON is a synonym for plain object. *It isn't*.

`json` pipe converts input into actual *JSON string*. So `(selectedMovie$ | async | json)` expression evaluates to a string and doesn't have `id` property.

It is helpful to use AoT compilation, because it allows to detect type problems in template and would likely result in type error in this case.

It should be `(selectedMovie$ | async).id` instead.

If `(selectedMovie$ | async)` is used more than once (like in this case), it will result in several subscriptions. It can be optimized by assigning it to local variable, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43327466/3731501):

```
<div *ngIf="movies">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(selectedMovie$ | async); let selectedMovie">
    ...
    {{selectedMovie.id}}
    ...
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Very smart trick. Really useful to store the value for later use within the same template. Any particular interest using the `<ng-container>` instead of a div?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547858/angular-2-ng-container . Tl;DR: it doesn't pollute layout.