# Use async pipe on method returning Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**How can I use async pipe when calling service method from template?**

This code works:

```
    <div *ngFor="let filename of filenames | async">
        <div>{{filename}}</div>
    </div>

    //code behind
    constructor(public importService: ImportService)
    {
        this.filenames = this.importService.list();  //returns Observable - from http.get
    }
```

but I would like to avoid assigning value to filenames (`this.filenames = this.importService.list();`) and call method directly from html:

```
<div *ngFor="let filename of importService.list() | async">
    <div>{{filename}}</div>
</div>
```

But this execute unlimited request to server. (As I would call `importService.list().subscribe()` in endless loop).

I also tried this ([source for ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325791/angular-using-async-pipe-on-observableobject-and-bind-it-to-local-variable-i)):

```
<div *ngFor="let filename of (o = (importService.list() | async))">
    <div>{{filename}}</div>
</div>


<div *ngFor="let filename of (o = (importService.list()) | async)">
    <div>{{filename}}</div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="importService.list(); let o">
    <div *ngFor="let filename of o | async">
        <div>{{filename}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But none works.
This [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7328) described exactly the same thing. I hope something has changed in year and half and this could be done.

**Edited:**
Desired effect can be achieved with several approaches.
First:

```
<div *ngFor="let filename of filenames">
    <div>{{filename}}</div>
</div>

public filenames: string[];

constructor(public importService: ImportService)
{
    this.importService.list().subscribe(res => this.filenames = res);
}
```

Second, more effective (shorter):

```
<div *ngFor="let filename of filenames | async">
    <div>{{filename}}</div>
</div>

public filenames: Observable<string[]>;

constructor(public importService: ImportService)
{
    this.filenames = this.importService.list();
}
```

and third even shorter (what I want to achieve):

```
constructor(public importService: ImportService) { }

<div *ngFor="let filename of importService.list() | async">
    <div>{{filename}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem with assigning to the component ? This is the recommended way of doing... If you **really** want to do this (I still don't get why ?!), you just have to return the same observable from your service everytime.

Comment: You could avoid writing at least 2 rows. Declaring observable variable and assigning. I really don't see a point why should I assign variable and then call async method on that variable. Would be a lot easier to just call | async on service method.

Comment: this execute unlimited request to server because each time Angular need to update the view so it must call `importService.list()` when an asynchronous action happen. just go with first approach as @n00dl3 said.

Comment: Thanks n00dl3 and Bougarfaoui El houcine, I understand why endless call to server. I edited my original post why I am looking for that, but apparently I can not go shorter then my second approach (n00dl3 answer).

Comment: There are scenarios where it can be done (note that I said "can", not "should"), but saving two lines of code is not part of these as it would require lot more work on the service side.