# How to Display Dynamic Updates with rxjs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

This question is based on an example from https://github.com/ParthibanRajalingam/demos

Only the initial values of the stock object are displayed using app.component.html:
[image]

```html
    <div class="card" *ngIf="stock$ | async; let stock">
  <div class="textBox">
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="h1">{{stock.name}}<div *ngIf="stock.increased"
          style="color: green ; margin: 0 10px 0 10px; float: right;">▲</div>
        <div *ngIf="!stock.increased" style="color: red ; margin: 0 10px 0 10px; float: right;">▼</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">Price: ${{stock.price}}   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The app.component.ts uses BehaviorSubject and Observable from rxjs:

```
private webSocket: WebSocket;
private subscription: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY; 
public stock: Stock = new Stock();
public stockSubject: BehaviorSubject<Stock> = new BehaviorSubject<Stock>(this.stock);
public stock$: Observable<Stock> = this.stockSubject.asObservable();

this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/stocks');
this.subscription = this.stock$.subscribe();
        
this.webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
    this.stock = JSON.parse(event.data.toString());
    this.stockSubject.next(this.stock);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.stock));
};
```

The Stock object has public attributes to avoid using the **any** type:

```
export class Stock {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
  price: number;
  increased: boolean;
  
  constructor () {
    this.name = 'Amazon';
    this.icon = '';
    this.price = 0;
    this.increased = false;
  }
}
```

The Angular application is a web service client that receives updated stock prices and calls **next** on the BehaviorSubject:

```
{"name":"Amazon","icon":"https://cdn.cdnlogo.com/logos/a/77/amazon-dark.svg","price":12.17,"increased":false}
{"name":"Amazon","icon":"https://cdn.cdnlogo.com/logos/a/77/amazon-dark.svg","price":12.72,"increased":true}
{"name":"Amazon","icon":"https://cdn.cdnlogo.com/logos/a/77/amazon-dark.svg","price":12.71,"increased":false}
```

What is missing to display the updated stock properties on the HTML page?  The original example does not use Subjects or Observables and worked for the author.

Comment: check if your API is returning data regularly, also validate if `this.stock = JSON.parse(event.data.toString());` is setting the value properly!

Comment: Confirmed the properties of this.stock are being set properly in the WebSocket onmessage routine. The onmessage routine is receiving a JSON event message once a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below working example for your reference!

[article](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe)

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BehaviorSubject, map, Observable, Subscription, interval } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';
import { Stock } from './stock.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div class="card" *ngIf="stock$ | async as stockData">
      <div class="textBox">
        <div class="textContent">
            <div class="h1">{{stockData.name}}<div *ngIf="stockData.increased"
              style="color: green ; margin: 0 10px 0 10px; float: right;">▲</div>
            <div *ngIf="!stockData.increased" style="color: red ; margin: 0 10px 0 10px; float: right;">▼</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail">Price: $ {{stockData.price}} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  // private webSocket: WebSocket;
  public stock: Stock = new Stock();
  public stockSubject: BehaviorSubject<Stock> = new BehaviorSubject<Stock>(
    this.stock
  );
  public stock$: Observable<Stock> = this.stockSubject.asObservable();

  // this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/stocks');
  // this.subscription = this.stock$.subscribe();

  ngOnInit() {
    interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        map(() => ({
          data: {
            name: 'Amazon',
            increased: Math.random() < 0.5,
            price: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
          },
        }))
      )
      .subscribe(this.onmessage);
  }

  onmessage = (event: any) => {
    this.stock = event.data;
    this.stockSubject.next(this.stock);
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fnonng?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fstock.model.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Changing to "as stock" did not change the behavior.  The "let" syntax came from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325791/angular-using-async-pipe-on-observableobject-and-bind-it-to-local-variable-i

Comment: @SteveLucord updated my answer with a working example!

Comment: When running through 'ng serve', an Internal server error is received: NG0400: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.   Accepting answer.